# Calculate Reverse Matrix?

Tags: c, matrix

Why should i get crash with this , where did i wrong !? :(

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<alloc.h>

const volatile max=15;

int    read(float[][max],float[][max]);
void   compute1(float[][max],float[][max],float[][max],int,int,int,float);
float  compute2(float[][max],int);
void   display(float[][max],float[][max],int,float);

int    main(){

    float  num[max][max],g[max][max],v[max][max],a[max][max];
    int dn,u;
    float det;
    int register i,j;

    dn=read(num,a);
    det=compute2(num,dn);

    for(i=0;i<dn;i++)
        for(j=0;j<dn;j++){
            compute1(a,g,v,dn,i,j,det);
        }

    display(a,v,dn,det);
    getch();

    return 0;
}

//****************************************************************************
int read(float num[][max],float a[][max]){

    int dn;
    clrscr();
    int register i,j;

    printf("\nenter degree of matrix:");

    scanf("%d",&dn);
    clrscr();

    for(i=0;i<dn;i++){
        printf("\n\n\nenter arguments of row[%d]:\n\n",i);

        for(j=0;j<dn;j++){
            scanf("%f",*(num+i)+j);

            *(*(a+i)+j)=*(*(num+i)+j);
        }
    }
    return dn;
}


//****************************************************************************
void   display(float c[][max],float inv[][max],int dn,float det){
    int register i,j;
    clrscr();

    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t    --ORIGINAL MATRIX--\n");

    for(i=0;i<dn;i++){
        printf("\n\t\t");

        for(j=0;j<dn;j++)
        printf("%10.3f",c[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t      --INVERSE MATRIX--\n");

    for(i=0;i<dn;i++){
        printf("\n\t\t");

        for(j=0;j<dn;j++)
        printf("%10.6f  ",inv[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n\t\tعؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤ؟");
    printf("\n\t\t³ determinan of matrix= %19.7f  ³ ",det);
    printf("\n\t\tہؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤؤظ");
}


//****************************************************************************
void compute1(float g[][max],float v[][max],float inv1[][max],int dn,int r,int c,float e){
    int col=0,row=0,add=r+c,y;
    float y1=1;

    if(add%2)
        y1=-1;

    int register i,j;

    for(i=0;i<dn-1;i++){
        if(i==r)
            row=1;

        col=0;

        for(j=0;j<dn-1;j++){
            if(j==c)
                col=1;

            v[i][j]=g[i+row][j+col];
        }
    }

    inv1[c][r]=y1*compute2(v,dn-1)/e;
}


//****************************************************************************
float compute2(float c[][max],int s){
    float *h=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)),h1=1;int y=s-1,k=s;
    int register i,j;

    while(y>0){
        for(i=1;i<k;i++){
            if(c[y][y]!=0)
                h[i-1]=c[y-i][y]/c[y][y];
            else{
                for(j=0;j<s;j++)
                    c[y][j]+=c[y-i][j];
                h[i-1]=c[y-i][y]/c[y][y];
            }
        }

    y--;
    k--;

    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        for(j=s-1;j>=0;j--)
            c[y-i][j]=c[y-i][j]-h[i]*c[y+1][j];
    }

    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
        h1*=c[i][i];

    return h1;
}
```

Comment: Could you please clean up your code a little bit? I'll take a look at this but it's a bit hard to read.

Comment: You might try running this with a debugger and see what line it crashes at. Presumably you're running past the end of an array.

Comment: The above comments are the real answer. Clean up the code: indendation, meaningful variable and function names, unit tests, refactor and you'll find the error soon enough, as well as standing some chance of someone being willing to read the code and therefore help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's quite a number of problems with your code. In compute2 you're allocating memory for.. a row?

```
   float *h=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)),h1=1;int y=s-1,k=s;
```

You're allocating space for just one float though. That could be a possible source of crashes.

You never actually deallocate the memory either, too.

Comment: i don't know why should i get down reputation , you are a life saver thanks , works fine now , my computer is damn old :/

Comment: Synmax: You're getting down voted because the code you posted was formatted poorly and showed signs of poor programming practices. Try to keep a consistent coding style and name your variables a bit better, this should reduce a number of issues you'll encounter.

Comment: @Synmax: You can also often figure these things out yourself, by running with a debugger, seeing that it crashes when you try to use an array at a given index, and realizing you haven't allocated enough memory for that array. Or perhaps you could use valgrind, and it might tell you *exactly* what you did wrong. Since these things are possible, people here often interpret you posting the question as a sign you haven't tried to fix it yourself, and are just giving up and asking us.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use debugging and logging tools rather than eyeballing the code. We don't even know what your crash is.

However here is one suspicious place

```
    if(c[y][y]!=0)
        h[i-1]=c[y-i][y]/c[y][y];
    else{
        for(j=0;j<s;j++)
            c[y][j]+=c[y-i][j];
        h[i-1]=c[y-i][y]/c[y][y];
    }
```

In both branches of the if...else you are dividing by `c[y][y]`. You know when it enters the `else` that is zero. Unless the `for` loop changes it you will have divide by zero. So I suggest you test it.

Comment: Not quite. Not that he adds the c[y-1] row to c[y], then does the division by c[y][y]. It's (probably) not actually zero. More likely is what I described in my answer.

Comment: I agree it's probably not zero if the OP's logic is correct. But we have no idea whether `j` reaches `y` in the loop. Suppose `s` was zero - the loop never executes. My point is that the OP should be testing the value of variables until he was sure the algorithm was correct (of course s/he should really use unit tests...)

Comment: s is initialized to dn-1, so it should be always positive assuming the user put in anything larger than 2 for the dimensions of the matrix. I do agree with your point that he should more thoroughly test his code, not to mention clean it up too.